# Mat datepicker format only one of multiple pickers

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have this issue where I need to have multiple datepickers in one component. However one of them needs to be only a year-picker so i've limited it and set the format, with `MomentDateAdapter`.
But every DP in the component is now formatted equally(to show only years), how can I limit only one dp and leave the others with default formats?

edit:
[Repro stackblitz w/o year pick limitations](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-anq1qg)

Comment: Can you provide a reproducer?

Comment: @MikeS. edited the post now have stackblitz

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't that thorough with my reserach.
I've found a solution to my issue.
The solution is to use a `@Directive` and provide your formats there in the directive's providers array.
I've had to use `moments` when handling dates otherwise no format was done.

[Github issue link](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/12035#issuecomment-515509919)

[Stackblitz solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-azrzg5?file=app/datepicker-moment-example.ts)