# Modify MatDatePicker for only month picking with overriding date format loacally

Tags: angular, angular-material, datepicker, date-format, angular-providers

I want to make a datepicker in an **Angular Material** application, only for month picking. In the **App Module** I set up some providers for date locales which is needed in the app globally.

```
 providers: [
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'hu-HU' },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'hu-HU' },
  ],
```

I found a solution for changing the date format for only one date picker, with the use of a directive that provides a different format when applied:

[Mat datepicker format only one of multiple pickers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62297962/mat-datepicker-format-only-one-of-multiple-pickers)

Here it suggests the same:

[Angular Material 6 datepicker different formats in same component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52677742/angular-material-6-datepicker-different-formats-in-same-component)

However, I cant change the locale or the format of the picker with the dircetive. **How could I override the provided values in the app module, with the directive?**

**My directive:**

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';
import { MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from '@angular/material/core';
export const FORMAT = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
};

@Directive({
  selector: '[DateFormat]',
  providers: [
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: FORMAT },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'en-EN' },
  ],
})
export class DateFormatDirective {
  constructor() {}
}
```

**Directive applied:**

```
<mat-form-field DateFormat>
  <input
    matInput
    [matDatepicker]="dp2"
    (click)="openDatePicker(dp2)"
    [formControl]="monthSelect"
  />
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dp2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker
    #dp2
    startView="year"
    (monthSelected)="closeDatePicker($event, dp2)"
  ></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

**Nor the locale or the format is overridden...**

**StackBlitz:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-basic-setup-vgmvgk?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use a date adapter based on **material-moment-adapter** instead of **NativeDateAdapter** in the **app.module.ts**. Or you can use it in the directive also:

```
import { MomentDateAdapter } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
*
*
*
providers: [
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'hu-HU' },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'hu-HU' },
    {
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useClass: MomentDateAdapter,
    },
  ],
```